# Using wildcard search in a parameter-based dynamic stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to use a wildcard search in a paramater-based filter stored procedure on the Name column but everything I have tried is either getting: The data types nvarchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator - or when it does compile I end up with Incorrect Syntax errors.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 1 = 1'
    + CASE WHEN @Name IS NOT NULL THEN
    N' AND NAME LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'' ELSE N'' END
+ CASE WHEN @AccountNumber IS NOT NULL THEN
    N' AND ACCOUNT_NO LIKE @AccountNumber' ELSE N'' END

DECLARE @params nvarchar(max) = N'
@Name varchar (20)
   ,@AccountNumber varchar(15)';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, @params, 
   @Name,
   @AccountNumber;
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic here in the first place? And if you do actually need dynamic sql you need to use two single quotes inside your string literal to delimit the string terminators.

Comment: @SeanLange - as for why I'm using dynamic, please see my post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342113/using-coalesce-in-stored-procedure-taking-3-times-longer-to-execute?noredirect=1#comment97409177_55342113) - do you mind showing me an example of how I'm to use two single quotes inside the string literal?

Comment: No offense meant Shane but do you seriously need an article to tell you how to delimit string terminators? You use '' instead of ' inside your string literal.

Comment: @Sean, thanks for the suggestion. I didn't realize you meant two single quotes around both ''%''. This worked as in the example provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going down the dynamic SQL route, you could achieve this doing the following:

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(10), @AccountNumber int;

--SET @Name = 'Smith';
--SET @AccountNumber = 12345;
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM MyTable' +
           CASE WHEN @Name IS NOT NULL OR @AccountNumber IS NOT NULL THEN NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'WHERE ' ELSE N'' END +
           ISNULL(STUFF(CASE WHEN @Name IS NOT NULL THEN NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'  AND NAME LIKE ''%'' + @Name + ''%''' ELSE N'' END +
                        CASE WHEN @AccountNumber IS NOT NULL THEN NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'  AND ACCOUNT_NO = @AccountNumber' ELSE N'' END,1,8,N''),N'') + N';';
PRINT @SQL;          
--EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,N'@Name varchar(10), @AccountNumber int', @Name = @Name, @AccountNumber = @AccountNumber;
```

Like Sean, I doubt this needs a dynamic query but *maybe* we have an overly simplyfied statement? Who knows. The above (if you uncomment the `SET` statements)  will return one of the below statements:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable;
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NAME LIKE '%' + @Name + '%';
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ACCOUNT_NO = @AccountNumber;
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NAME LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
  AND ACCOUNT_NO = @AccountNumber;
```

Comment: Now, @Shane, do you understand the above..?

Comment: Yes, I over simplified the post but I thought this would be adequate. I tried your example and it works great. I'm still trying to understand dynamic sql. If you see the link that I posted for Sean, the examples provided solved the problem of the long search times. Thanks.

Comment: No, I don't completely understand the logic. Why `SET @SQL = N'`? and why this: `@AccountNumber' ELSE N'' END,1,8,N'')`

Comment: `SET` set's the value of a parameter @Shane (it does what it says :) ). The final snippet is the end of a `CASE` expression  and the final 3 parameters of `STUFF`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you could skip the dynamic sql and do something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NAME LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' --no need to check if the parameter is NULL, if it is this will not return anything.
    OR ACCOUNT_NO = @AccountNumber --used equality here since you had no wildcard
```

Comment: OP uses an `AND`, so this *might* give incorrect values when 2 customers share a name (not uncommon).

Comment: @Larnu true enough. But seriously this is just a continuation of the catch all query they posted yesterday. :(

Comment: @Larnu they were using AND because they started the where predicate with 1 = 1. And then used AND to build it up. This just has all the signs of throwing code at the wall until something sticks without understanding.

Comment: That I won't argue with. :) I'll post a dynamic solution anyway, but agree, unlikely it needs it.

Answer (score 0):

And just to add another option to the mix, we can use this option for some catch-all-queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (NAME LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' OR @Name IS NULL)
  AND (ACCOUNT_NO = @AccountNumber OR @AccountNumber IS NULL)
OPTION( RECOMPILE);
```

The last part is important to obtain an optimal execution plan.

Comment: I don't fully understand the reasoning, but as suggested here: [link](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) using option(RECOMPILE) is not suggested.

Comment: It doesn't say that is not suggested, it just needs to be used with caution. I wouldn't recommend it for complex queries or queries that are run constantly. However, it's a way to keep code simple without major problems. This is also explained by Gail Shaw in [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/).